# Вывод на Chart из другого потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, диаграммы

Добрый день. Требуется выводить данные на чарт на главной форме из потока (`Thread`), который висит в фоне. Ситуация следующая: если компилировать без отладки, то данные выводятся, но через какое то время программа падает и на весь чарт отображается большой красный крест. Я поместил код вывода в блок `Try ... Catch` и вывел сообщение исключения. При первом же запуске выдает

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MainChart' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Я просто вывожу данные в серию по ссылке. Я так понимаю, должна быть конструкция для работы с другими объектами. Аналог `Synhronize` в `TThread C++`.

Answer (score 1):

.NET не позволяет обращаться к контролам напрямую из других потоков.

```
chart1.Invoke(new Action<double>(AddY), 3.14); // вызываешь из другого потока

private void AddY(double y)
{
    chart1.Series[name].Points.AddY(y);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Завтра попробую на работе

Comment: Добавлю, что полезно проверять значение свойства контрола `InvokeRequired`. Если оно ложно, можно вызывать метод напрямую. Если истинно — вызов идет из другого потока, и вызов делать нужно так, как показано выше.

Comment: Да, и более того — это не .NET не позволяет, это сама Винда не позволяет.

Comment: Сделал вызов функции через делегаты.Теперь все отлично работает. Спасибо. Сейчас возникла нелепая на мой взгляд проблема, данные отлично отображаются на чарте, но стоит только свернуть форму, и после разворачивания начинаются сильные тормоза программы...не подскажите из-за чего это может быть?